# Use `shortvrb` without needing to end the command manually

Tags: verbatim

Currently, using `shortvrb`, it's possible to define a single character to start, by itself, an inline verbatim command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\begin{document}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
foo |this is verbatim|
\end{document}
```

or similarly, with `fancyvrb`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
foo |this is verbatim|
\end{document}
```

In both cases -- as with `\verb!some verbatim text!` -- the symbol is required again to end the verbatim portion.  If it's left out, an error similar to "\verb ended by end of line" is produced.

---

Is there a way to (re)define `\MakeShortVerb` or similar, such that the newline will merely end the command, rather than producing an error? Ideally, one could then write something like:

```
\DefineAsymmetricVerb{\|}
This is some regular text.
Now some verbatim code that only needs a symbol at the start of the line, like:
| if 1 == 1
|     print 'All is well'
```

This would allow blocks (or single lines) of verbatim text without the clutter of

```
| if 1 == 1                |
|     print 'All is well'  |
```

or

```
\begin{verbatim}
 if 1 == 1
     print 'All is well'
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Isn't this `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, that would work, but in the context in which I'm wanting my verbatim text that would add undesirable clutter. I've added a clarification about that.

I'll happily grant that this is a problem that I could find other ways around, but I've gotten myself curious as to whether it's possible to just end \verb with a new line and what the mechanics are behind that being possible (or not).

Comment: how should short verb know, where to end verbatim text? for example in regular languages we use dots, comas to show where a sentence is finished ...

Comment: Verbatim mode has the tendency to go on forever.

Comment: @egreg It would definitely go on forever if  -- as I had accidentally done above -- I wrote `\begin` instead of `\end`

Comment: @Zarko At the line break (like the kids do today, with their text speak, or so I gather)

Comment: and what to do in case if the line is for example simply be broken (for some reasons). you try to jeopardize basic idea of markup languages.

Comment: @Zarko Granted! My interest in doing so was initially in order to get some (non-LaTeX) code to (temporarily) be displayable in  a draft document. In the process of trying to work out if it was possible, I got interested in the theory. I would never write a proper LaTeX document this way!

Answer (score 3):

You can, but you shouldn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`|=\active
\def|{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@\mbox{}%
  \owj@eol\catcode`\^^M=\active
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \verbatim@font\@noligs
  \@vobeyspaces\frenchspacing
}
\def\owj@par{\par\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\owj@eol{\let~\owj@par}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is some regular text.
Now some verbatim code that only needs a symbol at the start of the line, like:
| if 1 == 1
|     print 'All is well'
|
| else
|     error
| fi
\noindent This is some regular text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The master has spoken.

Comment: Fabulous, thanks so much; I'm going to have great fun getting my head around that! And as per another comment that I just posted ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415474/use-shortvrb-without-needing-to-end-the-command-manually?noredirect=1#comment1038396_415474 ), I'm totally with you on "You can, but you shouldn't."

Comment: (+1), however the " but you shouldn't" you should put in boldface! :-)

Comment: Interesting.  I assume "you shouldn't" because somehow this is dangerous for ... some reasons.  Maybe for the compiler, or linters, or error messages, or something.  Would it be possible to define an environment in which you permit this syntax, that way dangerous issues are contained?

Comment: @Addem The worst part is catching the end-of-line. This is always very fragile. Besides, adding a wrapper environment is useless, as there's already `verbatim`.